# 4th electrode in 3-Lead ECG

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics, ecg, electrode

Can I use 4th electrode for ground in 3-Lead ECG? As I know 3-Lead ECG must contain 3 electrodes

[image]

Source: commonly-termed-as-single-lead-recording_fig5_291972857&docid=vps8h4i3n1aU_M&w=850&h=686&hl=en-US&source=sh/x/im/4